# Code Vectorization that works on different array elements?

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

just started with matlab, and vectorization,
FF to problem:

What to do:

```
%n,t are vectors(1D arrays) EDIT: these are column vectors.
k=9;
i=1;
kv = 0.6*k:0.2*k:1.4*k;
[zs,zb] = size(k);
error1 = zeros(zs,1);
for k2 = kv
error1(i,1) = error_km(n,t,kv(i));
i= i+1;
end
```

where error_km is : (n and t are of same size)

```
function [ returnV] = error_km( n,t,k )
returnV = 0
    [a,b] = size(n);
    Nt = zeros();
    for i=2:a
        Nt(i,1) = (n(i-1,1)^-1 + k*(t(i,1)-t(i-1,1)))^-1;
        error1 = Nt(i,1) - n(i,1);
        returnV = returnV + error1*error1;
    end
```

The whole program takes about 3 to 4 minutes, for small test cases, 
i was able to make and understand simple vectorized alternatives for loops, but i am not able to make sense to vectorize this loop,

Any guidance?

UPDATE : 
in error_km, now i am using:

```
Nt = (n(1:a-1,1).^-1 + (diff(t(:,1))).*k).^-1 - n(2:a,1);
Nt = Nt.^2;
returnV = sum(Nt);
```

works good, but still in the main program i am forced to use a loop for iterating over kv, if i use kv(:) it passes the vector to function not a single value each time.
used this in main :  `error1 = error_km(n,t,kv.*1);`

is it possible to get rid of main loop also?

EDIT2, Soln :

To get rid of main loop just use arrayfun

Comment: What are the sizes of k, n and t initially? What is this code trying to do?

Comment: ^see if the edit provides more info, the code basically calculates error in observed and calculated value, n(observed value) and t(time) are 1D arrays read from file, both of same size

Comment: EDIT: added more code, to make it clear

Comment: Since the function `error_km` does not use Nt you could get away with not storing all values of `Nt` generated use `Nt=...` instead of Nt(i,1).  Or preallocate `Nt` by changing `Nt=zeros();` to Nt=zeros(a,1)`. I don't have an answer about vectorizing the code at this time.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but Its just a code snippet, not the whole code ;)

Comment: @TarunG The way you've written this code, isn't `zs` equal to 1? k is a row vector meaning that the the size in the first dimension is just 1 right?

Comment: yea, sorry, but it's a column vector,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some parts of the answer you seek, I trust that you can figure the rest out.  You can replace the expression:

```
t(i,1)-t(i-1,1)
```

with the (vectorised) expression

```
diff(t(:,1))
```

You can then replace your loop over `i` with the expressions:

```
Nt(a:-1:2,1) = (n(a-1:-1:1),1)^-1 + k*(diff(t(:,1))))^-1;
returnV = dot(Nt(:,1)-n(:,1),Nt(:,1)-n(:,1));
```

If I've read your code correctly and matched brackets properly that might be vectorised enough for your taste.

And as you've already been advised, you should preallocate `Nt`, in this case I would write:

```
Nt = zeros(size(n))
```

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't it be :

Nt(2:a,1) = (n(1:a-1),1)^-1 + k*(diff(t(:,1))))^-1;

?

Comment: also returnV = sum((Nt(:,1) - n(2:a,1)).^2); ?

Comment: @TarunG: you wrote the loop over a:-1:2 originally, if you want to change it go right ahead.

Comment: nope, its for a(2:a)(isn't it??) and anyways, i asked the above question, as i guessed diff would work with ascending index, am i right?

Comment: @TarunG: I got confused by the other answer.  You seem to be good to go now.

Comment: Thanks, HP Mark, that helped a lot, can you also have a look at the update?

Answer (score 1):

In `error_km` you don't preallocate `Nt`.  This step is important.  You can learn more about why in [this Matlab helpfile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f8-784135.html).

If you know the size of `Nt` you can set it in the call to zeros().  Otherwise you could restructure the loop:

```
function [ returnV] = error_km( n,t,k )
returnV = 0
    [a,b] = size(n);
    Nt = zeros();
    for i=a:-1:2
        Nt(i,1) = (n(i-1,1)^-1 + k*(t(i,1)-t(i-1,1)))^-1;
        error1 = Nt(i,1) - n(i,1);
        returnV = returnV + error1*error1;
    end
```

Comment: but we are still utilising the loops, is this vectorized approach??